# How to create a simple Autoencoder to select features from high dimensional dataset

Tags: feature-selection, autoencoder

I am trying to create a simple Autoencoder to select features based on a high dimensional dataset. I can understand, how AE works and how AE will reduce the dimensionality but I am looking for a sample or tutorial for the AE feature selection which is implemented based on the Keras DL tool. I would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: You might be able to build something that reconstructs your data using only a few of the original features - is this really what you're looking for?  Generally, an autoencoder won't select features, it'll only find a *low dimensional combination of features* that it represents in its hidden layer.

Comment: No, I am not looking for a pre-feature selection and apply the AE. I am trying to find out a sample based on the AE for feature selections. According to this (https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-deep-learning-methods-of-feature-selection), we can use stacked Autoencoders for feature selections but I was not able to find any sample.

Comment: There are different reasons to do feature selection. One is to reduce the dimensionality of your data to save computational costs - in this context it's not feature selection (i.e. selecting a subset of features), it's dimensionality reduction (re-representing your features more compactly with fewer dimensions).  The other is to find the most important/predictive features in your dataset. In this latter case, you'd be better off to use another feature selection method like LASSO or even a decision tree.